# Какой View передаётся параметром в onClick?

Tags: java, android

Есть у нас кнопка. Мы задаём ей `onClick` (назовём его так же — `onClick`).

Как он выглядит, все видели:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
}
```

Что за `View` передаётся параметром в этот метод?

Comment: View по которому кликнули, в данном случае - кнопка, которая у нас есть.

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации `Ctrl + клик` по неизвестному методу и откроются исходники, в которых обычно в комментариях есть пояснения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`View`, на которую вы вешаете `OnClickListener`, то есть ваша кнопка.